# Artifactory generates 0 byte package json for NPM artifact

Tags: artifactory

I am facing an odd situation where the initial npm publication went fine. But when moving/promoting the artifact to another local npm repository, which does not contain an artifact yet for this   artifact; artifactory succesfully moves the artifact. But fails with creating the corresponding package.json.

In the artifactory-service.log we see the following message:

`2023-01-12T09:11:52.521Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [c8198335dc788640] [.NpmPackageMetadataIndexer:402] [art-exec-24 ] - Preparing to write npm package metadata for repo 'npm_releases' on path '.npm/@<group>/<artifactid>/package.json' 2023-01-12T09:11:52.540Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [494934d19384b919] [j.r.n.PackageMetadataStream:68] [art-fixed-$s ] - Failed write java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed precondition. List argument metadata must not be empty at org.jfrog.repomd.npm.util.NpmUtils.updateAndGetLatest(NpmUtils.java:107) at org.jfrog.repomd.npm.util.NpmUtils.updateAndGetLatest(NpmUtils.java:100) at org.jfrog.repomd.npm.PackageMetadataStream.calculateLatest(PackageMetadataStream.java:128) at org.jfrog.repomd.npm.PackageMetadataStream.buildGroupMetadata(PackageMetadataStream.java:99) at org.jfrog.repomd.npm.PackageMetadataStream.writeInternal(PackageMetadataStream.java:77) at org.jfrog.repomd.npm.PackageMetadataStream.write(PackageMetadataStream.java:66) at org.iostreams.streams.in.OutputToInputStream$1.call(OutputToInputStream.java:140) at org.iostreams.streams.in.OutputToInputStream$1.call(OutputToInputStream.java:136) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) at org.artifactory.opentracing.TraceableRunnableDecorator.run(TraceableRunnableDecorator.java:40) at org.artifactory.concurrent.ArtifactoryRunnable.run(ArtifactoryRunnable.java:53) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) 2023-01-12T09:11:52.565Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [c8198335dc788640] [.NpmPackageMetadataIndexer:412] [art-exec-24 ] - Finished writing npm package metadata for repo 'npm_releases' on path '.npm/@<group>/<artifactid>/package.json`

I do not see how this relates to the uploaded artifact. As the generation of the package.json for the initial publication went fine. Next to this stacktrace I could not find anything in the log which relates to this.

I am able to reproduce this problem with artifactory version: 7.46.11 and 7.49.5

Could someone help explaining in what `Failed precondition. List argument metadata must not be empty at` means? And how to mitigate this situation?

I tried moving this artifact to other local npm repositories with same result. For unclear reasons in a populated repository as in a local npm repository(lets say the original repository which worked) which contains 3 artifacts with a different version number, but same group and artifactid a valid package.json was generated. This should work for this single artifact as well, but it doesn't.

Comment: how is the package composed and how is it deployed?
Seems issue with the scoped package, can you check for non-scoped package too?

Comment: We currently use node/npm to publish our packages. We did this successfully with non-scoped packages but also successfully for scoped packages. I verified in the package.json off the package that the name was actually scoped, and it is!

We do publish to our private artifactory. Next to the scoped name in the package.json we dont configure anything with the npm publish. Would something next to that be required? Up to now where able to publish multiple scoped packages like this without any problems.